# How to import product from English version to local language

Tags: multisite, import, bulk-import

I have a website in English and three other websites in Swedish, French, and Italian. I create products in English version websites and I want to copy that to these three local languages (and then start translating content).

Slug in attributes and categories in all three websites are identical, names of categories and attributes are different.

The problem I face is that:

- after importing it keeps local language attributes, and it creates attributes in English.
  Then I have old attributes in the local language and new attributes in the English version.
  Is there any way to import from English version to the local language without creating problems?

Note: the slug in both local and English versions are identical.

Example: slug in both websites is "book", the name in the English version is "Book", and in Swedish language is "Bok". After importing to the Swedish website, I have two attributes:

1. Slug: book, Name: Bok
2. Slug: book-0, Name: Book